# Can Windows CMD.EXE ever return an %ERRORLEVEL% of -1?

Tags: windows, cmd, errorlevel

I'm under the impression that the errorlevel provided back to command-line level scripting is exactly the value provided by a windows application to its Exit(..) call.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Presumably, an exit call might be called with "-1" as an argument, in spite of the fact that the error code would seem to be an unsigned number.

Does that value get through to a calling command script?
(Not that I want it.  I need a value which is clearly not a valid error number,
and isn't zero).

Comment: As I know, there are no bulit-in commands, that return negative errorlevels. But there are indeed applications, which do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
CALL :negerr 1
ECHO ERRORLEVEL = %errorlevel%
GOTO :EOF

:negerr
EXIT /b -%1
```

You mean like this?

Comment: I guess like that.  [Should have been the obvious trick].  Sigh.  (The windows error status values are all positive numbers).